# Javascript regex: How to extract an "id" from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: `comment_1234`

I want to extract the `1234` from the string. How can I do that?

**Update:** I can't get any of your answers to work...Is there a problem with my code? The alert never gets called:

```
var nameValue = dojo.query('#Comments .Comment:last-child > a[name]').attr('name');
alert('name value: ' + nameValue); // comment_1234
var commentId = nameValue.split("_")[1];
// var commentId = nameValue.match(/\d+/)[0];
// var commentId = nameValue.match(/^comment_(\d+)/)[1];
alert('comment id: ' + commentId); //never gets called. Why?
```

### Solution:

I figured out my problem...for some reason it looks like a string but it wasn't actually a string, so now I am casting `nameValue` to a string and it is working.

```
var nameValue = dojo.query('#Comments .Comment:last-child > a[name]').attr('name'); //comment_1234
var string = String(nameValue); //cast nameValue as a string
var id = string.match(/^comment_(\d+)/)[1]; //1234
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
someString.match(/\d+/)[0]; // 1234
```

Or, to specifically target digits following "comment_":

```
someString.match(/^comment_(\d+)/)[1]; // 1234
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work. I think there must be an error in the code which prevents it from completing the function because my alert never gets called.

Comment: Or just `someString.split("_")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function ExtractId(str){
    var params = str.split('_');
    return params[params.length - 1];
}

var id = ExtractId('comment_1234');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tesst = "WishID=1List"
var test = tesst.match(/WishID=(.*)List/);
alert (test[1]);

if(test[1]==""){
  alert('Empty');
}
```