# javascript regex find id in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse ID from string `/path1/path2/something/id/7272/more/path/8282/category/3131` and the problem is that the string could be different all the time but the very part of `/id/*` is the same all the time. So I'm trying to get it with the following regex but it seems doesn't work.

```
new RegExp(/^./\//ig/^\d+$/)
```

After matching the result should be `7272`.

Comment: And, what have you done so far? What are the results?

Comment: See [Javascript regex: How to extract an “id” from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388769/javascript-regex-how-to-extract-an-id-from-a-string), follow the same idea. BTW, `ig` != `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `/id/` part of the string for your matching too:

[`/\/id\/(\d+)/`](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mPDX6A8YhoBKdcdV)

```js
var str = '/path1/path2/something/id/7272/more/path/8282/category/3131';
console.log(str.match(/\/id\/(\d+)/));
```

Comment: You need to specify the preceding `\/` or this will also find `/anotherid/666/`

Comment: May belong to the usecase, yes. In his example this is no problem. I will extend the answer ... thx @Archer

Comment: No worries :-).

Answer (score -3):

Your regex should be `"/id/(\\d+)"`

Group: 1

Comment: well that looks a lot of easier.

Comment: @eisbehr Nope, it has no errors in this regex. Remember regex is independent on any languages. This is the original format of regex

So let's say. When I use the above regex in Java i have to escape it as : "/id/(\\d+)" 

In javascript, it should be : /\/id\/(\d+)/

Comment: There's a Javscript tag.  It's language specific.

Comment: @Archer I know, But I said "your regex" it means I wrote it in original syntax of regular expression

Comment: You say (as written above) **_"Your regex should be"_**, but it's a Javascript specific question so this answer is completely incorrect as the regex is syntactically wrong.

Comment: I'd personally delete this answer as it is misleading.

Comment: There was a formatting issue with the answer. It is not that incorrect, if used with `RegExp` constructor, it will work, and is even cleaner, IMHO, than a regex literal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's true. 
Why there are so many guys wanna put regex & language specific into 1 while regex has it own format?
When you use regex, you have to escape the regex by target language's specifics

Comment: You may add the JS snippet showing your regex also works if you care about downvotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew downvote is nothing to me, I just wanna make it clear about regex. 
As someone said, the answer should be: /\/id\/(\d+)/ .

From the aspect of Java language, I can say it's completely wrong with the same thought.
But no